# Can't extract tar.gz wordpress on EC2 Ubuntu

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, gzip, tar

I'm following this tutorial to install Wordpress on AWS Ec2 Ubuntu.

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-wordpress-on-ubuntu-20-04-with-a-lamp-stack

When I run this part

```
curl -O https://wordpress.org/latest.tar.gz
tar xzvf latest.tar.gz
```

I get this error:

```
gzip: stdin: not in gzip format
tar: Child returned status 1
tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now
```

I tried every kind of xzvf- combination and nothin seems to work.

Added here the download phase
[image]

Appreciate the help.

Comment: Your commands are ok. Try re-downlaoding the wordpress. Maybe it failed fully download.

Comment: Did it, still got error.

Comment: Did exactly your commands and it worked just dandy. What is the size of the resulting `latest.tar.gz` file? Maybe it's small and actually contains an uncompressed error message.

Comment: Did it. Just edit the Question.

Comment: Whats the size of the file that you are trying to uncompress. it may not be the actual wordpress bundle.

Comment: 12007? The downloaded file should be 12.3 megabytes. cat the downloaded file. I'll bet it's some HTML with an error message.